# Strange problem overriding one of LinearLayout's constructors

Tags: java, android

For some reason, Eclipse doesn't like the call to super(context, attrs, defStyle), yet it's happy with the other super calls. The error is "The constructor LinearLayout(Context, AttributeSet, int) is undefined".

I don't think the problem is with this code itself, but something else in the project's settings or something, since I adapted almost identical code from an example that did the same thing but for a RelativeLayout, which ran fine on my Eclipse setup in a test project.

Please Help :)

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    myInit();
}

public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    myInit();
}

public MyLinearLayout(Context context, int checkableId) {
    super(context);
    myInit();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [these javadocs](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/m5-rc15/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) the error is completely correct.

`LinearLayout` does not have that constructor. These are the two valid constructors:

```
LinearLayout(Context context) 
LinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, Map inflateParams)
```

Comment: Thanks, that would certainly explain it! Which begs the question - why does [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) seem to contradict the javadocs you posted?

Comment: Good question, jodes; I was wondering that myself - although, here's another thing - the android dev site (your link) seems to say that the third constructor requires an API level of 11. What version of SDK do you have installed/are you targetting?

Comment: Ah ok, I was targeting level 7 :)

Comment: Sorry - my google-foo was apparently weak. However, on the page you link to, on the far right of the constructor listing, there's a link for the constructor in question [Since: API Level 11](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#level11). CLicking on it shows it's only Andriod 3.0 that has that constructor. I'm going to wager that's not the version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

According to the developer site, the LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyle) constructor is only available in API version 11, so it won't work in earlier versions.